# Is the tensor product of two anti-symmetic tensors also anti-symmetric?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

If $w$ and $v$ are two totally anti-symmetric tensors, is the tensor $w \bigotimes v$ also a totally antisymmetric tensor?

Comment: $dx^1,dx^2\in \Lambda^1(\mathbb{R^2})$  but  $dx^1\otimes dx^2$ is not antisymmetric.

Comment: I'm just learning this stuff.. Are $dx^1$ and $dx^2$ cotangent vectors corresponding to the coordinate functions in the real two-dimensional Euclidean plane? Also, given a tensor, how do I know it's anti-symmetric or not? If can apply the anti-symmetrization map, I know I should get back the same tensor. Is this condition sufficient?

Comment: Yes they are. To see that $\tau^p$ it is not antisymmetric you can search for vectors $X_1,\dots, X_p$ such that when you exchange $X_i$ with $X_j$ lets call this set of vectors $Y_1,\dots, Y_p$ you have that $\tau(X_1,\dots,X_p) \neq -\tau(Y_1,\dots,Y_p)$ (indeed if $\tau$ is antisymmetric you should get a minus when you exchange two vectors). e.g. $dx^1\otimes dx^2(e_1,e_2) =1 \neq dx^1\otimes dx^2(e_2,e_1) = 0$

Comment: Okay. But how about $dx^1$ by itself? It takes as input only one tangent vector. How does one go about defining anti-symmetry of $dx^1$?

Comment: @IanDsouza: since $dx^1$ takes only a single vector as input, there are no pairs of vectors to exchange; so it is vacuously antisymmetric.

Comment: Could you also say that $dx^1$ is symmetric as well?